# Activity inside TabHost not getting onNewIntent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc

As the documentation says if that activity has set launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest, the intent will come in through the onNewIntent callback.

I have been unable to get this behavior when the activity was started by a TabHost. Instead of calling onNewIntent, the activity's onCreate method is called, resulting in a new instance of the activity on top of the activity stack.

This is my code for starting the intent:

```
// create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
            tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


            TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
            TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
            TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");

           // Set the Tab name and Activity
           // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
            tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WhenLogin.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            tab1.setContent(intent);
```

Has anyone else had this problem? If so, have they found a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "started by a `TabHost`"?

Comment: I am using tabs. When I didn't use tabs all worked fine.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider pasting in your source code to explain what you mean by "started by a `TabHost`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TabActivity`, and the general approach of putting activities in tabs, has been deprecated for **over 3.5 years**. Plenty of experts were warning developers away from it for a long time prior to that. Please use a modern tab solution, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, or `FragmentTabHost`, or even a plain `TabHost` using `Views` for tabs.

> As the documentation says if that activity has set launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest, the intent will come in through the onNewIntent callback.

That is only for activities started via `startActivity()` (and *maybe* `startActivityForResult()`, though using that in combination with `singleTop` worries me).

> Instead of calling onNewIntent, the activity's onCreate method is called, resulting in a new instance of the activity on top of the activity stack.

The "new instance of the activity" is not on the activity stack, because it is not used as a full-fledged activity. Instead, the UI is ripped out of the activity and put into your `TabActivity` as a tab.

Comment: Ok, I understand.
But I using nfc, which means I have to use activity and not fragments. (I need the method "On New Intent" for getting the NFC TAG). Is there a way to use tabs in activity? or replacing the OnNewIntent method in the fragment class?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3421416: "But I using nfc, which means I have to use activity and not fragments" -- not only do you have to use an activity, but it has to be a real activity. Whether that activity has tabs (e.g., via `ViewPager`) is immaterial, but it has to be a real activity.